# Memory Error pulling blob from google Storage

Tags: python

I am using Docker Registry API (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api) to pull blobs from the container registry of google. The blob size is around 900Mbs. While pulling this blob I get a memory error in Python as this :

```
 File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
MemoryError
```

Is there any way to pull this blob in resumable manner or chunk wise?

Comment: Are you running the python code form your local machine? or another GCP product?

Answer (score 0):

How are you pulling these layers? Are you using the docker tool or something else?

In addition to the official docker tool, you can try crane or gcrane (https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry)